# add image to a datagridview cell.

Tags: c#, database, image, visual-studio-2013, datagridviewcolumn

C#
hello, 
im trying to make a database with 6 columns (id, Brand, Model, Part, Info and Image)
i have everything setup correctly i can add new row( without image) and i have also made the row selectable to view more information on the "Info Column" and to view the picture in bigger detail. 
but the issue im having is how do i add an image to a specify "id" and to the cell under Image column.

what i want to do is:

i have selected a picture then i want to add that picture to the ID 3 and to the cell under Image column.

[image]

i may be asking for alot but i have tried all different things and nothing is working for me but i thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post what different things you have tried?

Comment: You can bind the image url or binary image as in your DB to the grid.
When you retrieve data from DB get the image URL or image from the DB.
Then you can bind that image by image URL or using the binary image to the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out away to add the picture to a specify cell. i just used a binding pictureBox. that easy.